# SQL - date group by year, month, days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

When I execute query

```
SELECT Item,
    [From date],
    [To date]
 from ItemDate;
```

I got this table:

```
('A1','2014-03-05','2014-07-21'),
('A1','2014-07-25','2015-03-15'),
('A1','2015-03-17','2016-03-17'),
('B1','2015-04-18','2016-06-16'),
('C1','2015-04-21','2016-02-12'),
('C1','2016-02-14','2016-08-29')
```

[image]

I want to calculate difference between date `[From date]` and `[To date]`  and get next table:

```
Item   Year    NoOfMonth  NoOfDays
A1    2014       9          ...
A1    2015       ...        ...
........

Group by Year and item
```

- `NoOfMonts` is number of months by year and item
- `NoOfDays` is number of days by year and item.

Any idea?

Comment: Please add DBMS used in tag list

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL server managment studio

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Do you want the difference in months and days between the `[From date]` to `[To date]` for every row in your table?

Comment: can you add your desired output for given tables

Comment: not answer to your question but it's better to not use spaces in column names.

Comment: Please add your required result. I see several values for A1 in your example, but your result table only seems to return one for each year. How do you make the split between those years & how to you group your data together to get to that 9 months result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use calendar table and some date functions:

```
;WITH calendar AS (
SELECT  CAST(MIN([From date]) as datetime) as d,
        MAX([To date]) as e
FROM ItemTable
UNION ALL
SELECT  DATEADD(day,1,d),
        e
FROM calendar
WHERE d < e
), cte AS(
SELECT  i.Item,
        DATEPART(year,c.d) as [Year],
        DATEDIFF(month,MIN(c.d),MAX(c.d)) as NoOfMonth,
        DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,MIN(c.d),MAX(c.d)),MIN(c.d)),MAX(c.d)) as NoOfDays
FROM ItemTable i
INNER JOIN calendar c
    ON c.d between i.[From date] and i.[To date]
GROUP BY i.Item, DATEPART(year,c.d),[From date],[To date]
)

SELECT  Item,
        [Year],
        SUM(NoOfMonth) as NoOfMonth,
        SUM(NoOfDays) as NoOfDays
FROM cte
GROUP BY Item,[Year]
ORDER BY Item
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Output:

```
Item    Year    NoOfMonth   NoOfDays
A1      2014    9           22
A1      2015    11          28
A1      2016    2           16
B1      2015    8           13
B1      2016    5           15
C1      2015    8           10
C1      2016    7           26
```

**EDIT**

Inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894600/sql-date-group-by-year-month-days-update).

```
SELECT  Item,
        [Year],
        CASE WHEN SUM(NoOfDays) < 0 THEN SUM(NoOfMonth)-1 
            WHEN SUM(NoOfDays) > 30 THEN SUM(NoOfMonth)+1 
            ELSE SUM(NoOfMonth) END as NoOfMonth,
        CASE WHEN SUM(NoOfDays) >= 30 THEN SUM(NoOfDays)-30 
            WHEN SUM(NoOfDays) < 0 THEN SUM(NoOfDays)+30
            ELSE SUM(NoOfDays) END as NoOfDays
FROM cte
GROUP BY Item,[Year]
ORDER BY Item
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

The main problem of such report - it is hard to define what is **1 month**, DATEDIFF just takes number from 2 dates and subtract one from another.

I have choose 30 as a days count in month, and now I compare values of days with 30 so we can add `+1` to month if the day count goes under zero or below 30

Comment: It seams ok, but in NoOfDays I need the number of the rest month like NoOfMonths = 9 and NoOfDays = 19....(19 because i dont have full month)

Comment: 9 month ~ 270 so you need 297-270 in `NoOfDays`?

Comment: some months have 30 days some 31 because i can not use 297 - (9*30)

Comment: I have changed my answer. The main logic is, for A1 2014 year: from `'2014-03-05'` to `'2014-07-21` there is 4 month and 16 days, from `'2014-07-25'` to `'2014-12-31'` (because `'2015-03-15'` is from 2015 year) there is 5 month and 6 days, sum is 9 month and 22 days.

Comment: Can you please look at this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894600/sql-date-group-by-year-month-days-update

Comment: Weird questions :) Hope my answer there helps.