# SQL - date group by year, month, days - update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I used code to calculate difference between two date group by year, months, date:

```
;WITH calendar AS (
SELECT  CAST(MIN([From date]) as datetime) as d,
    MAX([To date]) as e
FROM ItemTable
UNION ALL
SELECT  DATEADD(day,1,d),
    e
FROM calendar
WHERE d < e
), cte AS(
SELECT  i.Item,
    DATEPART(year,c.d) as [Year],
    DATEDIFF(month,MIN(c.d),MAX(c.d)) as NoOfMonth,
    DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,MIN(c.d),MAX(c.d)),MIN(c.d)), 
  MAX(c.d)) as NoOfDays
FROM ItemTable i
INNER JOIN calendar c
ON c.d between i.[From date] and i.[To date]
GROUP BY i.Item, DATEPART(year,c.d),[From date],[To date]
)

SELECT  Item,
    [Year],
    SUM(NoOfMonth) as NoOfMonth,
    SUM(NoOfDays) as NoOfDays
FROM cte
GROUP BY Item,[Year]
ORDER BY Item
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I found this code in [SQL - date group by year, month, days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872204/sql-date-group-by-year-month-days)

But not work for me...

When I execute my query

```
SELECT Item,
[From date],
[To date]
 from ItemDate;
```

I got

```
('A1','2013-08-27','2013-09-27'),
('A1','2013-09-28','2013-11-28'),
('A1','2013-11-30','2013-12-03'),
('A1','2013-12-31','2014-03-31'),
('A1','2014-04-01','2014-07-01'),
('A1','2014-07-02','2014-10-02'),
('A1','2014-10-03','2014-12-31')
```

and when execute code from this link [SQL - date group by year, month, days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872204/sql-date-group-by-year-month-days)

I get this:

```
 Item      Year         NoOfMonth     NoOfDays 
  A1        2013           4             -27
  A2        2014           10            58
```

This is not good.... It should be 3 months and 4 day for year 2013,
and for year 2014 11 month and 28 days

How to update the code to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last select to:

```
SELECT  Item,
        [Year],
        CASE WHEN SUM(NoOfDays) < 0 THEN SUM(NoOfMonth)-1 
            WHEN SUM(NoOfDays) > 30 THEN SUM(NoOfMonth)+1 
            ELSE SUM(NoOfMonth) END as NoOfMonth,
        CASE WHEN SUM(NoOfDays) >= 30 THEN SUM(NoOfDays)-30 
            WHEN SUM(NoOfDays) < 0 THEN SUM(NoOfDays)+30
            ELSE SUM(NoOfDays) END as NoOfDays
FROM cte
GROUP BY Item,[Year]
ORDER BY Item
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

The main problem of such report - it is hard to define what is **1 month**, DATEDIFF just takes number from 2 dates and subtract one from another.

I have choose 30 as a days count in month, and now I compare values of days with 30 so we can add `+1` to month if the day count goes under zero or below 30

Comment: thanks, i just edit this  CASE WHEN  SUM(NoOfDays) > 30
            THEN SUM(NoOfMonth)+ 1 
            ELSE SUM(NoOfMonth) END as NoOfMonth,
   CASE WHEN SUM(NoOfDays) < 0 
            THEN SUM(NoOfMonth)- 1 
            ELSE SUM(NoOfMonth) END as NoOfMonth,
        CASE WHEN SUM(NoOfDays) >= 30 THEN SUM(NoOfDays)-30 
            WHEN SUM(NoOfDays) < 0 THEN SUM(NoOfDays)+30
            ELSE SUM(NoOfDays) END as NoOfDays